# MATLAB のタイマーを使用して excel ファイルを作成するプログラムのエラー

Tags: c, excel, matlab

MATLAB のタイマーを使って、プログラムを実行した最後に一度だけ
excelファイルにデータを書き込もうとしています。

TimerCallback.mとtimer_sample.mを同じフォルダに入れて、timer_sample.mを実行します。
MATLABは「mac-64bitのバージョンR2017a」です。

以下のエラーメッセージが出て、excelファイルが書き出されず困っています。
**エラーメッセージ**

```
>> timer_sample
Warning: Unable to write to Excel format, attempting to write file to csv format. To write to an Excel file, convert your data to a table and
use writetable. 
> In xlswrite (line 179)
  In TimerCallback/callback (line 20)
  In timer_sample>@(varargin)mycallback.callback(varargin{:})
  In timer/timercb (line 34)
  In timercb (line 24) 
Warning: Unable to write to Excel format, attempting to write file to csv format. To write to an Excel file, convert your data to a table and
use writetable. 
> In xlswrite (line 179)
  In TimerCallback/callback (line 21)
  In timer_sample>@(varargin)mycallback.callback(varargin{:})
  In timer/timercb (line 34)
  In timercb (line 24) 
Callback executed
```

TimerCallback.m

```
classdef TimerCallback < handle
    properties  %public properties
        state;
        x_value;
        y_value;
        filename;
    end
    methods
        %constructor
        function this = TimerCallback(filename)
            if nargin > 0
                this.filename = filename;
            end
            this.state = true;
        end

        %callback function
        function callback(this, ~, ~)
            %consider using writetable instead of xlswrite. At least, use only one xlswrite.
            xlswrite(this.filename, this.x_value, 'sender');
            xlswrite(this.filename, this.y_value, 'receiver');
            this.state = false;
            disp('Callback executed');
        end
    end
end
```

timer_sample.m

```
mycallback = TimerCallback('data.xlsx');
mytimer = timer('TimerFcn', @mycallback.callback, 'StartDelay', 30);
start(mytimer);
mycallback.x_value = [mycallback.x_value, [1 2 3]];
mycallback.y_value = [mycallback.y_value, [4 5 6]];
mycallback.x_value = [mycallback.x_value, [7 8 9]];
mycallback.y_value = [mycallback.y_value, [10 11 12]];
%and so on... until the Timer completes
```

**試したこと**
タイマーを使わなければ、以下のプログラムでexcelファイルに問題なく書き出せることは確認しました。

```
global x_value
global y_value
global stat
stat = true;
x_value = [x_value [1 2 3]]
y_value = [y_value [4 5 6]]
x_value = [x_value [7 8 9]]
y_value = [y_value [10 11 12]]
filename = 'data.xlsx';
x_range = 'sender';
y_range = 'receiver';
xlswrite(filename, x_value, x_range) 
xlswrite(filename, y_value, y_range)
```

Comment: タイマーを使わず試したプラットフォームは、やはりMacでしょうか。`xlswrite`は、Windows以外のOSでは非常に制限がきつく、タイマーを使わなくても同じwarningが出ると思うのですが。

Comment: コメントいただきましてありがとうございます。タイマーを使わずに試したのもMacです。その時はwarningは出ましたが、csvファイルが書き出されました。Windowsであれば上記コードでうまくいくのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[xlswriteのオンラインヘルプ](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html)によると、下の方に

> #### 制限
>
> - コンピューターに Windows® 版 Excel が搭載されていない場合、または MATLAB® Online™ を使用している場合、関数 xlswrite は以下を行います。
>
>   - 配列 A をコンマ区切り値 (CSV) 形式でテキスト ファイルに書き込みます。A は数値行列でなければなりません。
>   - 引数 sheet と引数 xlRange を無視します。
>
>   この制限は (通常は Excel インストール環境の一部である) COM サーバーが使用できない場合にも適用されます。

とあります(回答時点では R2018b のもの)。Macに Windows版の Excelはインストールできない (Boot campで Windowsをインストールすれば Excelもイントールできますが...) ので、CSVでしか書き出せません。sheetか xlRange引数をお使いのようですが、それも無視されます。

[writetable](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html)という関数があるようなので、試してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 紹介記事(Q&A)はこちらの方が直接的だと思います。[Excelがインストールされている Mac 上の MATLAB で、xlsread 関数や xlswrite 関数を使用することはできますか？](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92107-excel-mac-matlab-xlsread-xlswrite)