# MATLABのタイマーコールバックに引数を渡して拡張性のあるプログラムを書く方法について

Tags: matlab

MATLAB のタイマーを使って、プログラムを実行した最後に一度だけ
excelファイルにデータを書き込もうとしています。

TimerCallback.mとtimer_sample.mを同じフォルダに入れて、timer_sample.mを実行します。
MATLABは「mac-64bitのバージョンR2017a」です。

考え方としては、[MATLABで複数の addAnalogInputChannel を同時に定義する時のエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54908/matlab%E3%81%A7%E8%A4%87%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE-addanaloginputchannel-%E3%82%92%E5%90%8C%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E5%AE%9A%E7%BE%A9%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC/54914#54914)と[MATLAB のタイマーを使用して excel ファイルを作成するプログラムのエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54899/matlab-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-excel-%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC)で書いたプログラムを組み合わせたプログラムを作成しようとしています。

**問題**
①TimerCallback.mで以下のように１つ１つ定義しているものをfor文でtimer_sample.mで定義した変数numの値だけxlswriteを個別に実行する方法がわからず困っています。

```
xlswrite(this.filename, this.x_value, 'sender');
xlswrite(this.filename, this.y_value, 'receiver');
xlswrite(this.filename, this.z_value, 'receiver');
```

②timer_sample.mにおいて、変数numの値だけタイマーコールバックをfor文で個別に呼び出す方法がわかりません。

**プログラム**
timer_sample.m

```
mycallback = TimerCallback('data.xlsx');
mytimer = timer('TimerFcn', @mycallback.callback, 'StartDelay', 30);
start(mytimer);
num = 3
for i = 1:1:num
    mycallback.x_value = [mycallback.x_value, [1 2 3]];
    mycallback.y_value = [mycallback.y_value, [4 5 6]];
    mycallback.z_value = [mycallback.y_value, [7 8 9]];
end
```

TimerCallback.m

```
classdef TimerCallback < handle
    properties  %public properties
        state;
        x_value;
        y_value;
        filename;
    end
    methods
        %constructor
        function this = TimerCallback(filename)
            if nargin > 0
                this.filename = filename;
            end
            this.state = true;
        end

        %callback function
        function callback(this, ~, ~)
            xlswrite(this.filename, this.x_value, 'sender');
            xlswrite(this.filename, this.y_value, 'receiver');
            xlswrite(this.filename, this.z_value, 'receiver');
            this.state = false;
            disp('Callback executed');
        end
    end
end
```

**ご回答を受けて補足**

timer_sample.mに関して

```
for i = 1:1:num
    mycallback.x_values{i} = [mycallback.x_values{i}  event.Data(i)]; 
  end
```

event.Dataはnum列からなる多次元行列で、その1列目をmycallback.r1_values、2列目をmycallback.r2_valuesにappendさせていきたいです。

TimerCallback.mに関して

```
this.x_values = cell(1,num); % cell配列の初期化(1x3の空cell配列)
```

とありましたが、event.Data(1)から取得されるのは行数が未定で１列の配列です。
またここでも、その1列目をmycallback.r1_values、2列目をmycallback.r2_valuesのように変数を入力numに応じで生成したいと考えています。

Comment: なぜタイマーを使うのでしょうか。データを書き込んでいる最中でも、他のタスクを行うからでしょうか。また、本来やりたいことは何でしょうか。例えば、30秒ごとに`num`回データを書き込みたいということでしょうか。

Comment: コメントいただきましてありがとうございます。
本来やりたいことは、異なるAnalogInputから同時に送られてくるリアルタイムデータを30秒後にまとめて書き出したいです。

Comment: ということは、例えば`num=10`の場合、およそ3秒ごとにデータを計測して、最後にデータをセーブしたいということでしょうか。

Comment: 10個のAnalogInputから同時にデータを計測して30秒後に各AnalogInputごとにデータをセーブしたいということです。

Comment: すみません、よくわかりません。では`num`とは、何の数なんでしょうか。

Comment: 返信が遅れて申し訳ございません。num=10の場合は10個、今回の場合は3個のAnalogInputです。numはAnalogInputの数で、timer('TimerFcn', @mycallback.callback, 'StartDelay', 30)の最後の引数で時間を設定しています。

Comment: 回答で誤植があったので修正しました。event.Data(1)は行数が不定で1列の配列なのに、1列目や2列目があるというのは、どういうことでしょうか。データの形式がはっきりしないので、回答のしようがありません。

Comment: event.Dataはnum列、不定行からなる多次元配列で、そのそれぞれ１列をmycallback.r1_values、mycallback.r2_values...にappendしたいという意味です。

Comment: receiverがnum個だとすると、senderは何個あるんですか。timer_sample.m の `for`ループから読み取れる情報と、説明されている情報が矛盾していて、よくわかりません。

Comment: 何度も申し訳ございません。これ以上オンラインで説明するのは難しく、ご迷惑をかけてしまうと判断して、別の方法での実装を試みます。この度はありがとうございました。おかげさまで新たな知見を得られることができました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

最終的に何をしたいのかが良くわからないので、はっきりしたことは言えませんが、とりあえず思いつくのは二つの方法です。

---

### タイマーを`num`個、作成する方法

timer_sample.m

```
num = 3;
for i = 1:num
    oneCallback = TimerCallback('data.xlsx');
    mycallbacks(i) = oneCallback;
    mytimers(i) = timer('TimerFcn', @oneCallback.callback, 'StartDelay', 30);
end

for i = 1:num
    start(mytimers(i))
end

for i = 1:num
    mycallbacks(i).x_value = [mycallbacks(i).x_value, [1 2 3]+num];
    mycallbacks(i).y_value = [mycallbacks(i).y_value, [1 2 3]+num];
    mycallbacks(i).z_value = [mycallbacks(i).z_value, [1 2 3]+num];
end
```

TimerCallback.m はそのままです (ただ、元のコードは`z_value`の宣言がされていませんが)。

但し、この方法だと、最後に`xlswrite`の書き込みで、タイマー同士で競合が起こる可能性があります。

---

### cell配列を利用し、`TimerCallback`クラスで`num`個分のデータを管理する方法

timer_sample.m

```
num = 3;

mycallback = TimerCallback('data.xlsx', num); % データの個数 num も渡す
mytimer = timer('TimerFcn', @mycallback.callback, 'StartDelay', 30);
start(mytimer)

for i = 1:num
    mycallback.x_values{i} = [mycallback.x_values{i} [1 2 3]]; % 波かっこを使っていることに注意
    mycallback.y_values{i} = [mycallback.y_values{i} [4 5 6]];
    mycallback.z_values{i} = [mycallback.z_values{i} [7 8 9]];
end
```

TimerCallback.m

```
classdef TimerCallback < handle
    properties
        state
        x_values % num個の数値の配列を入れるcell配列
        y_values
        z_values
        filename
        num
    end

    methods
        % constructor
        function this = TimerCallback(filename, num)
            this.filename = filename;
            this.num = num;
            this.x_values = cell(1,num); % cell配列の初期化(1 x num の空cell配列)
            this.y_values = cell(1,num);
            this.z_values = cell(1,num);
            this.state = true;
        end

        % callback function
        function callback(this, ~, ~)
            for i = 1:this.num
                xlswrite(this.filename, this.x_values{i}, 'sender')
                xlswrite(this.filename, this.y_values{i}, 'receiver')
                xlswrite(this.filename, this.z_values{i}, 'receiver')                
            end

            this.state = false;
            disp('Callback executed')
        end
    end
end
```

ただ、この方法でも

- xlswrite は、同じシート名が既にある時、上書きしてしまう
- そもそも xlswrite は Mac では、機能が非常に限定されている

ために、思う通りに動くとは限りません。

Comment: シート名を変更してwindows環境で実行したところ上手くいきました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: cell配列を利用し、TimerCallbackクラスでnum個分のデータを管理する方法で行い、ご提案いただいたサンプルは確かに動作しました。

しかしながら、今回の場合、numという変数で拡張性を持たせている一方で、データを格納するmycallback.x_valuesをx,y,zと定義しなければいけないのは、こちら側の質問の意図が伝わっておりませんでしたでしょうか。

Comment: @NPP 「データを格納するmycallback.x_valuesをx,y,zと定義」とは、どういう意味でしょうか。x,y,zというのは、変数でしょうか。

Comment: ご回答を受けて補足に明記いたしましたが、変数です。x,y,zはexcel書き出しにもあるように、senderやrecieverを指しているので（今回は簡単のため、numの数分のreceiverと考えた時にmycallback.r1_values、mycallback.r2_valuesと自動で生成したいです。